# Are custom posts included when getting a categories' posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, wp-query

Would `WP_Query('cat=1')` display custom post types, or is that something that I have to specify?

I have a custom post type, am assigning it to a category, and would like for it to be displayed when that category is visited, but that doesn't seem to be happening.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```
WP_Query('cat=1&post_type=any')
```

Or if you want just your custom post to show, put the name of it instead of any. More info in [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters)

Comment: If a custom post is under a category, will it show when that category is viewed?

Comment: you nwill need to add ?post_type=your custom post . Why not using taxonomies?

Comment: I don't want to change the theme code; I just want all posts under a category to be displayed. This used to work in previous versions of WordPress.